# Border Image bottom only

Tags: css, border-image

I am trying to add a border image ONLY to the bottom of a header. It's working in Chrome, but not Safari.

Here's the code :

```css
.header {
    border-bottom: 3px solid; 
    border-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ec57b9825bdfa44638daa1e/t/5ed57287a22a3463f755e9da/1591046791198/LTI-website-header-border-03.png); 
    border-image-width: 100%; 
    border-image-repeat:stretch; 
    border-top:none !important; 
    border-left: none !important; 
    border-right: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add -webkit- to your style.

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;
-webkit-border-image: url('...../test.png') 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
```

Comment: thanks! I tried this, but it still doesn't work. Am I applying webkit incorrectly?

Comment: -webkit-border-bottom: 3px solid;
  -webkit-border-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ec57b9825bdfa44638daa1e/t/5ed57287a22a3463f755e9da/1591046791198/LTI-website-header-border-03.png);
  
  -moz-border-bottom: 3px solid;
   -moz-border-image: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ec57b9825bdfa44638daa1e/t/5ed57287a22a3463f755e9da/1591046791198/LTI-website-header-border-03.png);
}

Comment: I was able to get the border just on the bottom with the code below, but there are transparent 'border gaps' on the other sides now.

Comment: -moz-border-image:url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ec57b9825bdfa44638daa1e/t/5ed57287a22a3463f755e9da/1591046791198/LTI-website-header-border-03.png") 0 0 3 0 stretch;
    -webkit-border-image:url("https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ec57b9825bdfa44638daa1e/t/5ed57287a22a3463f755e9da/1591046791198/LTI-website-header-border-03.png") 0 0 3 0 stretch;

Comment: Ive also tried border:collapse; padding:0px; margin:0px; spacing:0px; The gap around the header where the borders would be if they appeared are still there.